# How to give acess to the components of the fmx to a function in firemonkey C++?

Tags: c++, firemonkey

I Basically want to change the state of a component, for that, I was doing something like this

```
void desenharpilha2(TImage *b1, TImage *b2, TImage *b3,TImage *b4, TImage *b5)
{
        b1->Visible = False;
        b2->Visible = False;
        b3->Visible = False;
        b4->Visible = False;
        b5->Visible = False;
}
```

Basically, passing all the components that I need to change to the function, but I'm sure that there's a better way of doing that.

In short, I need a way to make the function have acess to all the components of the FMX without having to pass all the objects that I'm gonna change, because if I need to change for example, 15 objects, the code will be a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `desenharpilha2()` be a member of the FMX Form class that owns the controls you are interested in, eg:

```cpp
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
__published:
    TImage *b1;
    TImage *b2;
    TImage *b3;
    TImage *b4;
    TImage *b5;
    ...
public:
    ...
    void desenharpilha2();
};

...

void TMyForm::desenharpilha2()
{
    b1->Visible = False;
    b2->Visible = False;
    b3->Visible = False;
    b4->Visible = False;
    b5->Visible = False;
}
```

And then you can call `desenharpilha2()` on the desired Form object at runtime when needed, eg:

```cpp
TMyForm *someForm = ...;
...
someForm->desenharpilha2();
```